# Get space between text and bound of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm trying to get the distance between the text and the left side of a TextView. It uses the property `android:gravity="center"`.

[image]

I want to get the distance of the red bar (this red bar is not a part of the layout) to center the blue button. What should I do?
The dark area represents the bounds of the TextView.

I don't want to use a compoundDrawable because this view will change the color of the button randomly.

The code of the view (written in Kotlin):

```
class BallTextView: TextView {

  private lateinit var ballPaint : Paint
  private var ballRadius : Float = 10f
  private var ballColor : Int = Color.BLACK

  constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(ctx, attrs) {
    initializeAttributes(attrs)
    configBall()
  }

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(ballRadius, height.toFloat()/2, ballRadius, ballPaint)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
  }

  fun configBall() {
    ballPaint = Paint()
    ballPaint.isAntiAlias = true
    ballPaint.color = ballColor
  }

  fun initializeAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet) {
    val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ball_textview)
    ballRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.ball_textview_ball_radius, ballRadius),
        context.resources.displayMetrics)
    ballColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ball_textview_ball_color, ballColor)
  }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post your xml code

Comment: The XML makes no difference here.

Comment: Check out the `getLineBounds()` method. The `Rect` you pass as the second argument will have the horizontal inset as its `left` field value after the call.

Comment: @MikeM.Do you know any way to get the canvas of the TextView?

Comment: The `Canvas` is passed into the `onDraw()` method.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's ok.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I understand your point. I'm working to test this implementation :)

Comment: @MikeM. Can you create the answer? This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextView#getLineBounds(int, Rect)` method is what you want.

The first parameter is the zero-based line number, and the second is a `Rect` object that will hold the bounds values of the given line after the call. The `left` field of the `Rect` will have the horizontal inset of the line, which you can use with the radius of your drawn circle to figure its center's x coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

My another solution was:

```
  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    if (xPosition == 0f) {
      xPosition = (width - paint.measureText(text.toString())) / 3
    }
    canvas.drawCircle(xPosition, height.toFloat()/2, ballRadius, ballPaint)
    super.onDraw(canvas)
  }
```

@MikeM. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Oh, hey. Yeah, whatever works for ya. I'm not sure why you divide the difference by 3, though, but I assume it's just fine-tuning for your use case. Just FYI, the @username thing doesn't work in answers, just in comments. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!